# How to get all the rows which have been not selected in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to build two dataframes filtering rows from the original dataset, `df`.
Specifically, I selected all the rows having two fields, `A` and `B`, not null, defining a dataset called `df_train`.
I wanted to create a dataset, `df_test`, which includes all the rows not included in `df_train`, i.e. `df-df_train`.

I have tried as follows:

```
df_test=df[~df.isin(df_train)]
```

but I have got the whole dataset (`df` has 1107 rows, `df_train` 479).
The datasets have the following columns: `ID, A, B, C`.

I think it is not relevant the content of the dataset, but if you need, please let me know and I will add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the train set , it should carry over the original df's `index`

```
df_test = df.drop(df_train.index)
```